# React map through an array of objects and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have something as follows:

```
const [channelAndReadsArray, setChannelAndReadsArray] = useState()

var channelAndReads = []
const requests = channels.map((currentChannel) => {
    axios.get(serverRestAddress...
                        .then((result) => {
        var element = {}
        element.channel = currentChannel;
        element.reads = result;
        channelAndReads.push(element);
    })
                    })

Promise.all(requests).then(() => {
    setChannelAndReadsArray(channelAndReads)
});

            ...

if (!channelAndReadsArray) {
    return null
})


channelAndReadsArray.map((channelAndReads) => {
    console.log(channelAndReads)
})
```

This is giving me null values in the console log.
I am not sure what is wrong here

Comment: Please fix the code to make it a [mcve] or at least valid syntax.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the `.map()` callback

Comment: That is because, `axios` call is async. The loop would finish before even a single http call succeeds and so your console.log will not have anything. You need to wait until all the api is succeeded.There will be no value in channelAndRead coz nothing would be pushed by the time `console.log` executes.

Comment: @Panther _"That is because, `axios` call is async..."_ - No, because TO "waits" for the results with `Promise.all(requests)`. The problem is the missing `return` in `.map()`

Comment: If u think it waits then it waits, but i see there is no wait or the console getting invoked via a call back to see that it is waiting.. But if u say so.. yes then :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Promise.all()` to work, you need to return a promise from the `channels.map`. You can return each element, and then use the list in `Promise.all` to store them.

Example (not tested):

```
const [channelAndReadsArray, setChannelAndReadsArray] = useState()

const requests = channels.map((currentChannel) =>
  axios.get(serverRestAddress)
  .then((result) => ({
    channel: currentChannel,
    reads: result
  }))
)

Promise.all(requests).then((elements) => {
  setChannelAndReadsArray(elements)
});

if (!channelAndReadsArray) {
  return null
})


channelAndReadsArray.map(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `request` array would be empty since you are not returning anything from the .map, a cleaner approach without pushing into an array with async code may be

```
const [channelAndReadsArray, setChannelAndReadsArray] = useState();
const requests = channels.map(async (currentChannel) => {
           return axios.get(serverRestAddress...)
           .then((result) => {
                var element = {}
                element.channel= currentChannel;
                element.reads= result;
                return result;
             })
           });
Promise.all(requests).then((results) => { setChannelAndReadsArray(results)});

if (!channelAndReadsArray) {
     return null
});
channelAndReadsArray.map((channelAndReads)=>{
     console.log(channelAndReads)
});
```